# Returning Iterators instead of underlying Container itself when access to the Container needed

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator

In my program at quite a few places I need to access and modify a std::map data structure. Right now I have a method called *getMap()* which essentially returns reference to the std::map. I am thinking of returning iterators to std::map instead of the map itself for better encapsulation and performance. Is it a good idea to do something like this or returning the map is as good as returning iterators as far as encapsulation and performance is concerned?

Comment: I would say from a OO perspective this is bad design. Better would be that the class that holds the map has methods that can do the manipulations you need.

Comment: Returning iterators like that is not going to do you any good. Think ahead about how you will receive the iterator:

std::map<HisType*, MyType*>::iterator it = getMapIterator();

Note that you have already re-declared the map (syntax-wise). If you are trying to save yourself some typing - that's not the way to go about it. Of course, you could typedef the declaration, but that just adds more clutter. With different parts of the app holding different iterators - things will get really messy.
Consider making a firm decision to stick with the reference to the map as opposed to returning iterators

Answer (score 0):

If you really just need a reference to the `map` then why return iterators?

If you need to be pointed at a specific part of the map, iterators don't always encapsulate that well (are they const?  reverse?  random access..?  your calling routine may want to be protected from such details, and bare iterators don't provide that protection).  `boost::range` may provide a better solution.

With some other containers (e.g. vector), iterators will be invalidated if another routine modifies the container before they are used.  Depending on the semantics of your program you might think this breaks encapsulation.

Comment: Map has the important property that inserting a new element into a map does not invalidate iterators that point to existing elements. Erasing an element from a map also does not invalidate any iterators, except, of course, for iterators that actually point to the element that is being erased.

Answer (score 0):

I think you reduce the usefulness of your function when you return iterators of the whole map.  The consumer of the function could simply write getMap().begin() to get the iterator.  On the other hand, they might not be interested in the elements at all, they may want to `clear()` it or `swap()` it.

However, when some ***subset*** of a collection is being output, e.g. a range or some elements selected by predicate, returning the data via an output iterator is much better then returning a **reduced** collection.

The standard library does this all the time, e.g. the `copy()` algorithm:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
    OutputIterator copy ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result )
{
    while (first!=last) *result++ = *first++;
    return result;
}
```

Here `result` can append the elements to another collection class (with `back_inserter`), output to the screen, or even process the elements without storing them anywhere, e.g. computing statistics on the item in the collection.

Comment: I don't really follow the answer here. Are you saying that returning iterator is a bad idea? But functions accepting OutputIterator is okay. May be I am missing something. Also, you mentioned generate() algorithm but in the example it is copy().

Comment: @PavanTotala "generate" is a typo, I'll fix it.  My point is returning an iterator to the whole map is useless, the user could just do that with myMap().begin().  In the second paragraph I intended to point out some subset of the collection is returned, e.g. a filtered subset or range, returning iterators is a very flexible way to go.  I'll edit.

Comment: @PavanTotala: I must have been asleep when I wrote that.  I've edited it significantly, please let me know if it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same in the past but now prefer to return a reference to the whole collection. I worry about the iterators staying valid. For example if I use an iterator to delete an entry are they both still valid or do I need to get them again? Returning the collection feels like exposing more but I feel it is safer.